# jquery dynamic button click not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, button

I am generating some buttons dynamically with dynamic ids. I wish to handle each button's click based on its id. But that's not working.

Following is my code:

```
var del_id = "del"+countPage+"-"+questionCount;
 html+='<tr><td><input type="button" value="delete" id="'+del_id+'" /><td><input type="button" value="Copy" id="copy_id"/></tr>';
        $("#"+del_id).click(function(){
                                alert("jkhkjh");
                              });
```

If I give static id instead of del_id, then it works. Where am I getting wrong? How do I solve this?

**edited:solved**

```
html+='<tr><td id="'+del_id+'"><input type="button" value="delete" id="'+del_id+'" /><td><input type="button" value="Copy" id="copy_id"/></tr>';


        $(document).on("click", "#"+del_id, function(){
                       alert("jkhkjh");
                       });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use [**`Event-delegation`**](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) to hook the events with elements which are loaded dynamically.

Try,

```
  $(document).on("click", "#"+del_id, function(){
```

Or try like this, dont register events for each and every buttons since they are performing the same task.

```
  $(document).on("click", "[type='button'][id^='del']", function(){
```

Or add a common class to that button element and try like this,

```
  $(document).on("click", ".buttonClass", function(){
```

Comment: this works but I get the alert 2 times. Any idea? I just want the alert one time

Comment: @z22 which method you had adopted for your code..?\

Comment: $.on(click)- the one you suggested

Comment: i have included the solved code in my question edit- please review

Comment: @z22 Please note that Id must be unique.. You have assigned saeme id for two elements in your code.. Just change that as a class.

Answer (score 1):

Try this for dynamically  created buttons

```
$(document).on('click', 'buttonId/Class', function(){
   // Do something.
})
```

Comment: this works but I get the alert 2 times. Any idea? I just want the alert one time

Comment: you are using same id on two element, on td and input too. Id should be unique on the page.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
$(document).on("click", "#"+del_id, function(){

});
```

Comment: this works but I get the alert 2 times. Any idea? I just want the alert one time

Comment: your td id and input id is same so only you get 2 alerts change this

Answer (score 0):

You are giving the same id to 2 different DOM elements (TD and input). Id's are supposed to be unique.

jQuery then gets only the first DOM element that it finds.

Answer (score 0):

`**.live()** -` 
This method provides a means to attach delegated event handlers to the document element of a page, which simplifies the use of event handlers when content is dynamically added to a page.

`$( "#dymanic" ).live( "click", function() {
  alert( "Goodbye!" ); // jQuery 1.3+
});`

Refer to this documentation

https://api.jquery.com/live/

Answer (score 0):

if your controls are being added dynamically on page, they should be handled with special events that take future events into account. like `on()` or `delegate()`.

I will prefer `delegate()` as I used it numerous times.

```
$('body').on("#"+del_id, 'click', function(){
   //Do something.
});
```

**Note:** with `delegate()` or `on()` you have an advantage of attaching multiple events handlers and make your selector search faster as you can specify the parent element to search within. In this case I mentioned `body` as parent selector. you can specify a more closer parent node.